# Approximating 2 linear functions in a continuous way

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, mathematical-modeling

I have some function $f(t,y)$ which behaves as follows: It is linear with gradient $g$ up to a time $T$ (i.e. $y = gt $). At time $T$ is suddenly switches to have gradient $g'$ which lasts for a time $dt$ before the gradient switches back to $g$. This behaviour repeats with period $T$

**I want to approximate this behaviour via some analytical function**. Whilst I could use some piecewise linear construction, I would prefer to have a continuous description, understanding that I will lose something in accuracy.

**Can anyone suggest an appropriate form to approximate this function?** My best approach so far involves taking the general gradient as

$$ g t \sin \left( \frac{2\pi}{T} t \right) + g t \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{T} t \right)$$

but this doesn't give 'sharp' enough transitions between the two gradients, nor account for the timescale over which the two gradients last.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function $$\ln(\exp(x)+1)$$ might be helpful

Comment: I am struggling to see why! Could you please expand further?

Comment: My idea (which I haven‘t fully thought through) is that this function is $\approx 0$ when $x<0$ and $\approx x$ when $x\geq$ so maybe some linear combinations of this function can give a good approximation. See for example this plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln%28exp%2810x%29%2B1%29%2F10%2C%20x%3D-2..2

Comment: The first derivative is an offset square wave and thus you only have to integrate that plus a dc offset.   So the question is representing a square wave.  The normal way is the trigonometric series and then integrate.  If you don't like that you can use delta functions as the second derivative.   Compressing the infinite number of delta's is possible in the frequency domain but just leads to an infinite number of sine/cosine terms in the "real" world.   I can write it all in the answer section but it would just be mathematical restatement.  There is a small gotcha in there, but not much.

Comment: Concerning my last: you are stuck with an infinite series, if you restrict yourself to a "elementary" functional series; this is induced by kinks.